# Problem : Installation ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine with virtual box (version 4.2.16) on my MacBook Pro. However, at the end of the installation, I am told to remove installation media and tray and then press enter. As I do not use installation media but only an iso file (provided by ubuntu website), I just pressed "enter" but nothing happened. My guess is that pressing any keys doesn't have any effects in my case (I cannot see any character when pressing on character keys).

So I shutdown the machine and relaunched it. Then, the OS told me he cannot detect my graphic card (or devices) and my only possibility is to use ubuntu 12.04 in a terminal.

Do you have any hints on this situation ?

Thank you in advance.

Joachim

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual box tool bar click devices, then cd/dvd, and click remove disk if you still have it attached.  You'll want to change the display settings as well.  While the VM is not running go to the virtual box manager (the window that opens when you first launch virtual box).  Highlight your vm in the list and click settings.  In the new window click display from the options on the left.  Move the video memory up (I recommend at least 128mb) and check the Enable 3d acceleration box.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this, but still, I have no device to remove. So I powered off the machine, again. And I restarted it, but I got the same messages:

"The system is running in low graphic
Your screen, graphic card, and input device settingscould not be detected correctly"

Comment: @Joachim Did you change the display settings as well?  Also, try terminal mode, and when the terminal prompt appears, type: startx

Comment: Yes, I boosted the grahic options, enabling 3D acceleration and allocating 128MB video memory => nothing changed.
With "startx" command => I get a list of services stopped and restarted, however it is now blocked saying:
"Stopping save kernel messagest/sanedaemononsing daemon    [OK]"
Then, nothing ...

Comment: @Joachim  What are the system settings?  Just like you changed the Display settings, this time, choose System instead of display.  For each of the 3 tabs, what are the settings (skip the boot order settings)?

Comment: Ok, so the system settings are :

Mother board : 
-RAM 3665 MB
I have no control over the following settings :
-Chipset PIIX3
Advanced functionnality : IO APIC (disabled) - EFI (disabled) nternal clock UTC (enabled) - pointing device (enabled)

Processor :
-1 processor
-100 % allocated ressources
-PAENX enabled (I have no control here)

Acceleration:
(I have no control over these two)
-VT-X/AMD-V enabled
-Pagination enabled

Comment: @Joachim All of those are optimal settings.  At this stage, I'd recommend reinstalling the Ubuntu OS in the VM.

Comment: Ok, that's what I did several times though. I find something weird here : each time, the end of the installation process asked me to restart the computer; when shutting down the different running processes, it also asked me to press "enter" but I couldn't. When I pressed enter nothing happened, so I was forced to power off the machine, maybe it could come from this ?

Comment: Did you click in the vm window before pressing enter?  Your input devices should be "captured" by the VM when issuing commands.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to install my machine on a ubuntu 12.04 with virtual box, but I got the same problem. Maybe it comes from the iso file that I download on ubuntu website.